# How can I avoid the "Attribute v-b-modal is not allowed here" warning in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, bootstrap-modal, vue-js-modal

In a Vue.js project I am using learning to use [Modals](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#toggle-modal-visibility) from BootstrapVue. In my code I have a file `Items.vue` with something like this:

```
<div v-b-modal="'modal-' + query.id">     // this is line 15
    ...
</div>

<b-modal :id="'modal-' + query.id">
    <p class="my-4">
        hello
    </p>
</b-modal>
```

It works well. However, Intellij IDEA with the Vue.js plugin keeps beeping with the Warning:

> Warning:(15, 5) Attribute v-b-modal is not allowed here

The thread [Vue Attribute is not allowed here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000084779-Vue-Attribute-is-not-allowed-here) suggests that this happens with non-.vue files, but it is not the case here.

Replacing `v-b-modal="..."` with `:v-b-modal="..."` (that is, with `:` before the attribute to make the binding more explicit) removes the warning, but then the code does not work.

I am working with Intellij IDEA 2018.1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA version you are using is very old, **Vue.js** support has been significantly improved since v. 2018.1. In particular, [WEB-38028](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38028) was fixed in 2019.2. Please consider upgrading IDEA to the most recent version, *BootstrapVue* directives are correctly recognized there

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have a perpetual fallback license, so I cannot upgrade to the 2019 : (